# Pass data and functions to child components , not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have an issue while passing data from parent component to child **AccountsDropDown**. As per the below code i could pass the depositAcct param to the child , but not the selected value and the onValueChnage methods .

So as per the current code these are the 2 issues am facing

- The selected value is not rendering
- OnValueChange event is not working , its not set the parent state.

This is my Parent component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";   
const transferType = ["Transfer", "Pay Loan"];

export default class a2aTransfer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            mode: "start",
            selectedTransferType: transferType[0],
            fromAcct: "",
            toAcct: "",
            amt: "",
            memo: ""
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ fromAcct: this.context.depositAcct[0].desc });
        this.setState({ toAcct: this.context.loanAcct[0].desc });
    }
    render() {
        TransferForm = () => {
            return (
                <Container>
                    <Content>
                        <Form>

                            <View style={styles.item}>
                                <Text note>From Account</Text>

                                <AccountsDropDown
                                    selectedValue={this.state.fromAcct}
                                    depositAcct={this.context.depositAcct}
                                    navigation={this.props.navigation}
                                    onValueChange={itemValue => this.setState({ fromAcct: itemValue })}
                                />
                            </View>

                        </Form>
                    </Content>
                </Container>
            );
        };


        if (this.state.mode == "start") {
            return <TransferForm />;
        }
        return <TransferConfirm />;
    }
}
a2aTransfer.contextType = MyContext;
```

This is my child component

```
  import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Picker, Icon } from "native-base";
import { Dimensions, Platform } from "react-native";
export default class accountsDropDown extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Picker
                selectedValue={this.props.selectedValue}
                mode="dropdown"
                iosHeader="Choose To Account"
                style={{ width: Platform.OS === "ios" ? undefined : Dimensions.get("window").width }}
                iosIcon={<Icon name="arrow-down" />}
                onValueChange={() => this.props.onValueChange}
            >
                {typeof this.props.depositAcct != "undefined" &&
                    this.props.depositAcct.map((acct, idx) => {
                        return <Picker.Item key={idx} label={acct.desc} value={acct.masked} />;
                    })}

            </Picker>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onValueChange` is a function so you need to call it in the child component with the value:

```
    <Picker
        selectedValue={this.props.selectedValue}
        mode="dropdown"
        iosHeader="Choose To Account"
        style={{ width: Platform.OS === "ios" ? undefined : Dimensions.get("window").width }}
        iosIcon={<Icon name="arrow-down" />}
        onValueChange={(value) => this.props.onValueChange(value)}
```

If you don't need to transform `value` then just pass the function directly:

```
onValueChange={this.props.onValueChange}
```

Comment: Davin Tryon:  It worked , thanks , do you know why the selected value is not populated first

Comment: I can only guess that `""` is treated as falsey.  So, that initial value doesn't select anything.

Answer (score 0):

You have written ok code, just check that are you getting data from context.

console your selectedValue in render method and check that data getting from context or not

```
render() {
    console.log(this.props.selectedValue);
    return (
        <Picker
            selectedValue={this.props.selectedValue}
            mode="dropdown"
            iosHeader="Choose To Account"
            style={{ width: Platform.OS === "ios" ? undefined : Dimensions.get("window").width }}
            iosIcon={<Icon name="arrow-down" />}
            onValueChange={() => this.props.onValueChange}
        >
            {typeof this.props.depositAcct != "undefined" &&
                this.props.depositAcct.map((acct, idx) => {
                    return <Picker.Item key={idx} label={acct.desc} value={acct.masked} />;
                })}

        </Picker>
    );
}
```